# Setting cookie directly on response returns None in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-views, httpresponse

I have written a `RegisterView` in Django like so:

```
class RegisterView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        request_body = parse_request_body(request)
        email = request_body.get('email')
        fullname = request_body.get('fullname')
        password = request_body.get('password')
        user = self.register_user(email, fullname, password)
        csrf_token = get_token(request)
        response = JsonResponse({'user': user.serialize()})
        response.set_cookie('csrftoken', csrf_token)
        return response
```

This code works fine but when I try setting the cookie directly on `JsonResponse`, a `ValueError` is raised because the view returns `None`:

```
class RegisterView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        request_body = parse_request_body(request)
        email = request_body.get('email')
        fullname = request_body.get('fullname')
        password = request_body.get('password')
        user = self.register_user(email, fullname, password)
        csrf_token = get_token(request)
        return JsonResponse({'user': user.serialize()}).set_cookie('csrftoken', csrf_token)
```

Why is that?

Comment: `set_cookie` does not return anything so when you return `response.set_cookie` you are returning nothing https://github.com/django/django/blob/720abed34304ec410c04a2e7a7dec7be4dae0d61/django/http/response.py#L213-L275